# What is the best to build a virtualized table with dynamic row heights (based on content)?

Tags: react-table

Trying to build a virtualized table with dynamic row heights based on the content within them. The only thing I have seen somewhat useful is passing a `rowHeight` to the `<VariableList/>` component, but would have to know the height in the beginning. Is the only way to do this measuring each inner container using refs? Not sure if that would even work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do so with `react-virtual` that will be easy to integrate and customize.